# Mocking GraphQL API with MSW for Testing

Tags: testing, graphql, msw

I'm trying to mock graphql API for testing react app but facing a problem

the handler is:

```
import { graphql } from 'msw'
    
export const postsGql = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'first post title',
    body: 'first post body',
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    id: 5,
    title: 'second post title',
    body: 'second post body',
  }
]
```

Define handlers that catch the corresponding requests and returns the mock data.

```
export const graphqlHandlers = [
  graphql.query('posts', async(req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.data(
        postsGql,
      ),
    )
  }),
]
```

my test file:

```
    it('Should return posts when clicking fetch with graphql button', async() => {
  render(<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>)

  expect(screen.getByRole('heading', { name: 'MSW Testing Library Example', level: 1 })).toBeDefined()

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Fetch Posts GraphQL' }))

  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByLabelText('loading'))

  postsGql.forEach((posts) => {
    expect(screen.getByRole('heading', { name: posts.title, level: 2 })).toBeDefined()
    expect(screen.getByText(posts.body)).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

but faced this error:

```
Missing field 'posts' while writing result [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "first post title",
    "body": "first post body"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "second post title",
    "body": "second post body"
  }
]
```

I will appreciate any kind of help
thanks